# Asp.Net Web Application will not accept Email as Username

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, web-applications

I just created an ASP.NET web app in Visual Studio 2013. I haven't looked at ASP.NET in 3 years, so I am getting up to speed on a few things. It has some nice "out of the box features" such as Login and Register. However when I try to register with an email as a username, i.e. me@gmail.com, I get an error from a asp Literal Control saying it will not except the @ sign. Only numbers and letters. Where is this being set? Is it built in functionality of Asp.Net.Identity.Core?

I need to allow my web app to accept emails as usernames.

** edit ** I should mention I am using web forms.

Comment: They seem to change this a lot, but I thought the latest implementation *was* to use emails rather than usernames. Did you just create this? Or could you just make another project? I wouldn't suggest that otherwise, but it sounds like you haven't done much in this one already anyway, so it might be easier than any conversion process.

Comment: The latest templates do generate the code for this. The old ones don't.

Comment: We have no idea how your application is set up, what validation it uses and so on. You really have to investigate this issue yourself, all we can do is guess and throw the most common scenarios to you until you shout bingo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your `UserManager` is created set the `UserValidator` to allow for emails. This code was taken from the latest MVC template...

```
var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
// Configure validation logic for usernames
manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
{
    AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
    RequireUniqueEmail = true
};
```

Comment: Thank you. This code was not generated in the web form project. but its works perfectly. FYI, "RequireUniqueEmail = true" property is not recognized. Perhaps this is only for MVC?

Comment: No you can use it for webforms as well. You might check what version of identity you are using.